# View Data table in highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

how can i toggle the data table in high-charts from another button not from the exporting options in high-charts , when i click it once it should show the data table  below the chart again i clicked on that it should hide the data-table, and i  have the N number of graphs so it should be dynamic for all the charts

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<button onclick="toggleDataTable()">
Toggle Datatable
</button>
<script>
    function toggleDataTable(){
        var chart= $('#container').highcharts()
        chart.update({
                exporting: {
                    showTable: true
                }
            });
    }

Highcharts.chart('container', {
exporting:false,
chart: {
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: null,
    plotShadow: false,
    type: 'pie'
},
title: {
    text: 'Browser market shares in January, 2018'
},
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
},
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        showInLegend: true
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'Brands',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [{
        name: 'Chrome',
        y: 61.41,
        sliced: true,
        selected: true
    }, {
        name: 'Internet Explorer',
        y: 11.84
    }, {
        name: 'Firefox',
        y: 10.85
    }, {
        name: 'Edge',
        y: 4.67
    }, {
        name: 'Safari',
        y: 4.18
    }, {
        name: 'Other',
        y: 7.05
    }]
}]
});

</script>
```

for the reference please go through this link:

https://jsfiddle.net/GnanaSagar/roL5mhu1/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `showTable` is an attribute from the `exporting` options. You cannot set `exporting: false` then. You must set it like this if you don't want to see the exporting button on top right:

```
  exporting: {
    enabled: false
  },
```

Then for the `onclick` function, you should probably use something like:

```
  function toggleDataTable() {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts()
    chart.update({
      exporting: {
        showTable: !chart.options.exporting.showTable
      }
    });
  }
```

But it does not remove the table after clicking back. 
So I suggest you manually remove the table element when `chart.options.exporting.showTable` is going from `true` to `false`:

```
if (chart.options.exporting.showTable) {
      var element = document.getElementById("highcharts-data-table-0");
      element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    }
```

[See updated jsfiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/3urwt5eq/1/)

Comment: HI THanks for the response how can i unshow the datatable

Comment: @Gnana I've just updated the answer. See the jsfiddle :)